# Can NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe improve performance while reading the same file multiple times?

Tags: ios, nsdata

Say I have below code:

```
-(NSString *)getNameForCode:(NSString *)code {
    NSError *error;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"data.txt" options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];
    NSString *name = [self getNameFrom:data];
    return name;
}
```

if `getNameForCode` function can be called many times, will `NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe` option improve the performance for `dataWithContentsOfFile`? I am not sure how iOS implement it, cache the file in the memory, so it will be returned immediately if read the file again?

I am thinking use `NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe` or make `data` static to improve the performance. But not sure which is better. For my guess, I want to use `NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe` instead of `statc`